# unknown type name `socklen_t`

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, osx-lion, xcode4.3

I have Xcode 4.3.1 installed. I am getting unknown type name `socklen_t` error despite of the required include in `SCNetwork.h`

```
#ifndef _SCNETWORK_H
#define _SCNETWORK_H

#include <Availability.h>
#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> // required include
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
```

Am I missing any include?

From Terminal:

```
➜  ABC git:(master) ✗ xcodebuild  
=== BUILD NATIVE TARGET ABC OF PROJECT DEF WITH THE DEFAULT CONFIGURATION (Release) ===
Check dependencies
2012-03-19 10:20:43.360 xcodebuild[42278:4403] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x401387be0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2012-03-19 10:20:43.362 xcodebuild[42278:4403] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'objective-c'.
Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x objective-c -c /dev/null 2>&1
2012-03-19 10:20:43.410 xcodebuild[42278:4403] error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1" UserInfo=0x401523f80 {NSLocalizedDescription=Non-zero exit code 127 returned from shell command: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1, NSLocalizedFailureReason=No such file or directory}
2012-03-19 10:20:43.411 xcodebuild[42278:4403] Warning:  Couldn't discover the 'gcc-4.2' compiler's built-in search paths and preprocessor definitions for language dialect 'c'.
Compiler: /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
Reason:   /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -v -E -dM -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk -x c -c /dev/null 2>&1
Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair in the default keychain


** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Check dependencies
(1 failure)
```

Comment: `<sys/socket.h>` should include the necessary headers that define `socklen_t` properly, so something is likely wrong with your project or build configuration or something.  Post the preprocessor output (via the **Product → Generate Output → Generate Preprocessed File** menu option).

Comment: Preprocessed File is not highlighted.

Comment: So what?  If you want help, post the preprocessor output.

Comment: I meant, I can't click it since its not highlighted. Is there any other way to see that output?

Comment: Huh, that's strange.  I'm not having any issues with Xcode 4.2 (which also does syntax highlight the preprocessor output).  Maybe try quitting Xcode, reloading, and re-preprocessing?

Comment: Post a screenshot of the first page of the preprocessor output maybe?  If all else fails, you can run the compiler on the command line, but that involves figuring out all of the compiler options your project is using.

Answer (score 1):

Import [SystemConfiguration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Networking/Reference/SysConfig/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001027) framework.

Comment: Its there in the frameworks folder. `SCNtwork.h` is in that folder only.

Comment: are you getting 'socklen_t' does not name a type?

Comment: unknown type name 'socklen_t'

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20090706/018877.html).

Comment: Ya read it before also, I have `#include <sys/types.h>` before socket.h

Comment: Did you try a clean build yet?  Sometimes Xcode complains despite the fact that you've fixed the problem.

Comment: Yes I am cleaning and then building every time.